# Tests breaking after adding new configuration to jest

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest

I have a problem in my application when running my tests, every time I run my test script (`"test:cov": "jest --runInBand --coverage --watchAll=false --detectOpenHandles --forceExit"`) all my tests pass, but the script breaks, as in the example image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45B4R.png)

This problem started after I added a new path to the roots property in jest.config.js, as in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TapGt.png)

Does anyone know why this happens or have you experienced something similar?

I was using jest on version `29.5.0` and ts-jest on version `29.0.5`, and I solved the problem by just setting jest to version `27.2.5` and ts-jest to version `27.0.3`.

I am using the NestJs framework

Comment: How does the script break? Your image doesn't make it clear. Can you take the text from the image and add it to a code block instead?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.